# Unit testing dialog boxes pop ups using moq in mvvm prism based application

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I am unit Testing view model in mvvm application which uses prism. I am using moq to unit test view models . I encountered a problem that I am unit testing a method which inside itself call another method and which further calls a password dialog box to pop up . since I am unit testing the very first method so how can I suppress the dialog box pop up as I have no control till my function returns back.Moreover I also want to unit test whether dialog box has popped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make your VM testeble by writing a thin UIService which will raise your popups and dialogs. This will gain you testibility (it will be easy for you to write a mock service) and a good design approch in general, as we do not wnat our view model to raise pop ups (imagine you would want to reuse the vm in a phone\tablet app).

Here is a sketch:

```
        public interface IUIService   
        {   
            bool ShowPopUp(....);

            DialogResult ShowDialog(...);

            ..  
        }
```

Comment: Yes we have written a static class UIService class that holds all the implementation for dialog boxes but inside the view model methods we are calling that UIservices method which binds itself with xaml and tries to pop up the dilaog . Do you think its a wrong appraoach? If not then How can I suppress this call inside my method while unit Testing.

Comment: The best would be to work with dependency injection and not with a static class. Second best is working with an inteface (IUIService) within your view model's cto'r, initiating a mock implementation of the interface and providing it to who ever is initiating your view model. But again, dependency injection is classic in this case.

Comment: what if we don't want to refactor the code because of many dependency on third party code and also to avoid constructor from flooding . is there any workaround to Test these type of scenario using moq or any other technique.

Comment: I don't see a way to supress the popup without modifying code. That is exactly the reason why using services is a good parctice, to avoid situations like this one..